# Drag & drop behavior in fullcalendar v5 timeGridDay view

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I have a list of events that the library allows me to drag up or down in the timeGridDay view.
I noticed that when I drag the element I can take it out of the bounds of the fullcalendar component and then it's like floating outside with the mouse to where I drag it until I place it where the library allows me to drop there.

My question is, can I prevent the drag outside the component's borders?
I want it to drag either up or down but not have the ability to pull it out

I'm interested in this - events in fullcalendar will drag only within the boundaries of the element of the library, in practice I can also take them outside the boundaries of the central element of fullcalendar

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So what if the user drags the item outside the calendar boundary? Presumably they can't drop it there?